# Not able to delete files using "forfiles" command, but able to extract them

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, forfiles

I am trying to delete files older than a certain time period.

I have problems deleting a txt file of certain format.

File: KB4054981_20180130_060034933-Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1-MSP0.txt.

When I try to echo all txt files, the above file gets printed. However, I try to delete it, it comes up with "it could not find the file".

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The filename has a space in it, so the del command sees it as several files.

Comment: You're asking to recurse subdirectories, so use `@PATH` not `@FILE`.

Comment: L.Scott Johnson: Could you please suggest how should I have the search mask to filter the file and delete if possible?

Comment: What Windows version are you using? Windows Vista onward? I think I remember `forfiles` changed in Windows XP or something, and it was not included by default; recent versions of `forfiles` include quotes around its values `@FILE`, `@PATH`, etc., so I am a bit confused...

Answer (score 0):

As well as the advice I've already provided in my initial comment, you should note that directories will also pass through with the default pattern, you're needlessly specifying. As directories aren't deleted using the `Del` command, you should therefore filter those out:

```dos
ForFiles /P "C:\Test" /S /C "Cmd /C If @IsDir==FALSE Del @Path"
```